# Where can I see built in backups taken by SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

So far I know, using Azure sql database built-in backups, I can restore the the database using **Point in time restore** as long as the time is with in the retention period.
But I want to understand, how Azure manages this automated backups or where can I find the backups taken by Azure.

Any article, which will help me understand, How Azure sql automated backups system works behind-the-scenes, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups) is the official document covering this.

Quote:

> Full database backups happen weekly, differential database backups
>   generally happen every few hours, and transaction log backups
>   generally happen every 5 - 10 minutes. The first full backup is
>   scheduled immediately after a database is created. It usually
>   completes within 30 minutes, but it can take longer when the database
>   is of a significant size. For example, the initial backup can take
>   longer on a restored database or a database copy. After the first full
>   backup, all further backups are scheduled automatically and managed
>   silently in the background. The exact timing of all database backups
>   is determined by the SQL Database service as it balances the overall
>   system workload. 
>   The backup storage geo-replication occurs based on
>   the Azure Storage replication schedule.

Edit:
you cannot find the backups taken by Azure. Since the service is managed for you, you have no business looking at backups. You're supposed to let that go and trust the service you're using ;) (by Rick van den Bosch)

Comment: As an addition: _you_ cannot find the backups taken by Azure. Since the service is managed for you, you have no business looking at backups. You're supposed to let that go and trust the service you're using ;)

Comment: I think this comment should be added as an answer